# big.Int to big.Float conversion in Go

Tags: go

I can convert big.Float to big.Int by using `<*big.Float>.Int(nil)`, but how can I do backwards?

Looking for something like this:

```
bigint := <*big.Int>.Float()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SetInt`:

```
big.NewFloat(0).SetInt(intValue)
```